# What happens to the energy that isn’t conserved in inelastic collisions?

Tags: energy, collision

When a very sticky object hits the ground and sticks to it, does the loss of energy simply go to putting stress on the materials and trying to deform the object or ground? If the object is rigid and both the object and the ground are quite strong though, and they don’t get damaged at all (if that is possible), then what happens to the energy that the object had as it was in motion before it hit the ground? Maybe vibrations, but then those would just dissipate, so where would that energy go? I find it hard to think it could all go to heat or sound, but I guess that might be possible.

Comment: Even if you don't take into account the energy loss caused by heat or sound. When an object collides, it gives and receives force. And the force must be represented by A and B interacting with each other. The ground is not immovable. It's just that the mass is so huge that it doesn't seem to move. It doesn't seem to be confusing if you make that clear.